# Dynamic drop down list for different countries, states, geographic locations?

Tags: php, html, mysql, autocomplete, gis

I am having my users to enter their city, state, and country. But my dilemma is how to manage it dynamically so that I can control what is entered while having correct spelling and formatting.

For instance, I currently have a static drop down for each state.

```
<select>
     <option name="state" value="AL">Alabama</option>
     <option name="state" value="AK">Alaska</option>
     <option name="state" value="AZ">Arizona</option>
     <option name="state" value="AR">Arkansas</option>
     <option name="state" value="CA">California</option>
     ....
 </select>
```

This works fine obviously, but doesn't scale at all if the user is outside the US. It also falls short in regards to different countries and cities. I have thought of using text fields, then saving them in a separate database and using the JQuery autocomplete plugin for generating the list but it doesn't seem like the best way to do it.

Comment: You can manage it like, 1st select country, then based on that country id, load the states of that specific country, then after selecting state, populate the cities of that specific state in a drop down

Comment: @baig772, that is true. But that would require me to look up every state and country in the entire world and enter into my database. It would be easier to use a web service but I'd really like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: there are databases available which contain lists of all countries and even cities e.g.: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html

Comment: What I would do is use some existing database with all countries etc etc. Then use Javascript (Ajax) so that if the user types the first letter (A for example) a dropdown with all countries starting with A appears (pulled from database so you dont have to write it out). Next allow a state field appear and do the same as before finishing with cities.

Comment: @icecub, Ok, that is inline with what others have said. It's a viable solution if I can download an existing database from the internet with this data already in it. I'd still appreciate other alternatives.

Comment: @newBee, thank you for that information, I never new it existed.

Comment: It seems you're in luck. I find it interesting to write a working example for this, but it's going to take time. It's quite a lot of work. No promisses! If you wish to stay in contact about this, look at my profile page.

Comment: @icecub, Well if you can find the time, I'm interested in what you can come up with!

Comment: @EternalHour Could you contact me through email on my profile? There's some info I need from you and comments are not supposed to turn into a chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so after several hours I've written an application based on the MySQL world database: [MySQL world Setup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html)

The code for the entire application is way to large to put in an answer so I'll provide Pastebin links for each seperate file, aswell as a link to a working example of the script and a download link for the Zip archive.

I'm sure the code can be improved further, but I'll leave that up to you.

**Requirements**: MySQL world Database / jQuery

1. index.html: [index.html](http://pastebin.com/niegWMek)
2. style.css: [style.css](http://pastebin.com/prdeQMMS)
3. country.js: [country.js](http://pastebin.com/ikhibXfK)
4. dbconnect.php: [dbconnect.php](http://pastebin.com/zyuMpLfp)
5. get_country.php: [get_country.php](http://pastebin.com/CRpUX0Wj)
6. get_states.php: [get_states.php](http://pastebin.com/qcEpdCrY)
7. get_city.php: [get_city.php](http://pastebin.com/gC5YbrKM)
8. get_data.php: [get_data.php](http://pastebin.com/U7XQNk3x)

**Working Example:**

9. [Country, State, City selector](http://icecub.nl/selector/)

**Zip Archive Download (DB NOT included!):**

10. [selector.zip](http://icecub.nl/selector.zip) (currently down)
11. [Virus Total Analysis of above file](https://www.virustotal.com/nl/file/afafa78149e4f4eba84a4ddea1e0c8afeb49b88c02889ad930f5c68bfbf25d10/analysis/)

I'm working on an updated script due to the popular demands on this question. It will be added soon.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this, it's a great solution. I look forward to seeing for myself what can be done with your script. At this point, it seems that my best option is implementing a database for this which I don't want to do but may have no choice. I'm going to hold out for a few days before accepting this answer so hopefully there will be some more ideas.

Comment: Can you add database export of countries and states?

Comment: @llioor What exactly do you mean by that? If you wish to export countries and states, you should use your db manager (like phpMyAdmin for example) for that. If you mean something else, please explain in more detail.

Comment: @icecub Thank you for your replay. You wrote "DB not included".... What I meant is there any place I can get a DB export of: Countries, States (with country_id). PLUS I wish the get on the countries table an indicator as "is_subdivision" which will tell me if have to include state in the shipping address format for this country. Thank you in advanced my friend!

Comment: @llioor I'm sorry I can't really help you with that. I've never had the need to work with such databases myself. I simply downloaded a basic one and turned it into a working script to answer this question. There are lots of databases you can find with Google. Most will cost money, but there are some free ones as well. You just need to check what kind of information the database includes to see if it matches your needs. After that you'll need to write a simular script like this one. I don't mind helping you out with that once you've got the database.

Comment: @EternalHour - if you don't want to use a database to hold your countries and cities etc. then you could always export or convert one of the free SQL dumps available to XML.