# dynamic country hotel Category drop down using ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want country - hotel - Category......

in my code if i select country - hotel coming perfectly but if i select hotel, then category not coming good...

how to right a code for three drop down using ajax function - index.php

```
<?php 

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("greenthai",$conn);






?>






<html>
  <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

      <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){


               $("#country").change(function(){
                     var country=$("#country").val();
                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"gcity.php",
                        data:"country="+country,
                        success:function(data){
                              $("#city").html(data);
                        }
                     });
               });


               $("#city").change(function(){
                     var city=$("#city").val();
                     $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"gcat.php",
                        data:"city="+city,
                        success:function(data){
                              $("#cat").html(data);
                        }
                     });
               });






           });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
        Country :
        <select name="country" id="country">
          <option>-select your country-</option>
        <?php

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT * from city ");
        while($country=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        ?>


        <option value=<?php echo $country["cityname"];?>> <?php echo $country["cityname"]; ?></option>


 <?php 
        } ?>
        </select>


        City :
        <select name="city" id="city">
            <option>-select your city-</option>
        </select>

         Sub city :
        <select name="cat" id="cat">
            <option>-select your city-</option>
        </select>


  </body>
</html>
```

**gcity.php**

```
<?php
  include "db.php";

 $country=$_POST["country"];
  $result=mysql_query("select * FROM hotel where city ='$country' ");
  while($city=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<option value=$city[hotelname]>$city[hotelname]</option>";

  }
?>
```

**gcat.php**

```
<?php
  include "db.php";

 $country=$_POST["city"];
  $result=mysql_query("select * from cat where hotel  ='$country' ");
  while($city=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo hi."<option value=$city[cat]>$city[cat]</option>";

  }
?>
```

Comment: First of all: Stop using mysql! It's deprecated and insecure! Secondly: I've written something simular a while ago here. You should be able to adept it quite easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069761/dynamic-drop-down-list-for-different-countries-states-geographic-locations/26076664#26076664

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could explain more what's the result show, because it looks fine at first look (maybe you should try):

```
echo"<option value=$city['hotelname']>$city['hotelname']</option>";
```

See this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClRZzquik1c 
or this: http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/
for more information (details and best practice)

Comment: getcat.php - i did not received the value $country=$_POST["city"]; What is the problem. if $_POST["city"]; value cant received ... how to get the value of $_POST["city"];

Comment: You need to test if it's set before: ` if(isset($_POST["city"])) { /* do your work...*/ } `

Answer (score 0):

If you change php code in 
**gcity.php**

```
<option value="<?php echo $city[hotelname];?>"><?php echo $city[hotelname]; ?></option>
```

**gcat.php**

```
<option value="<?php echo $city[cat]; ?>"> <?php echo $city[cat]; ?></option>
```